# Google API url use by javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I have this url as json object which is provided by google API.

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyAo6DqmlMti9ID7lL532A7-6Miu1QHcMqI&cx=013881670411723352605:b1y6-jfsiki&q=web%20developer?alt=json-in-script&callback=listEvents

I want to use javaScript and want to see complete json object.This is my script code , but it doesn't work. please help me , i am struggling from 3 days.

```
function listEvents(root){
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyAo6DqmlMti9ID7lL532A7-6Miu1QHcMqI&cx=013881670411723352605:b1y6-jfsiki&q=web%20developer?alt=json-in-script&callback=listEvents', function(data) {*/
        alert(root)    
    });   
}

function init() {
    listEvents();
}

window.onload = init;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The output is in JSONP format and not JSON

> JSONP({JSON})

Jquery JSONP: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

```
(function($) {
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyAo6DqmlMti9ID7lL532A7-6Miu1QHcMqI&cx=013881670411723352605:b1y6-jfsiki&q=web%20developer?alt=json-in-script&callback=listEvents';

$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'listEvents',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       console.dir(json);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

BTW your *Google Daily Limit Exceeded*

Comment: so how does it work ? i have no experience with JSONP

Answer (score 0):

You are giving a callback option in url that is again a call to listEvents(). That is not correct. Use your own success callback. this will work:

```
function listEvents() {
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyAo6DqmlMti9ID7lL532A7-6Miu1QHcMqI&cx=013881670411723352605:b1y6-jfsiki&q=web%20developer?alt=json-in-script', function (data) {

       console.log(data)
    });
}
```

[Demo example](http://jsfiddle.net/91d2k3xw/8/)